# How to use template engine without using any controller in standalone NestJS Application?

Tags: nestjs, chatbot, template-engine, telegraf.js

I'm trying to create telegram chatbot application using [nestjs-telegraf](https://nestjs-telegraf.vercel.app/docs/)

And then I've idea to use template engine like what has been taught from [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc), to render the reply message for each message has been received.

But, I don't find any way how to do that. All I have got is everyone using `@Res res` parameter in their method, and then just `return res.render(...)`

Is there any way to that?

I don't want to manually format the reply message by using ` and using string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a callback parameter from `res.render()`, like this:

```
import { Response } from 'express';
import { Post, Controller, Res } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller()
export class MyController {
  @Get()
  root(@Res() response: Response) {
    await response.render(
        'index',
        { variable: 'My variable' },
        function (error, html) {
            console.log(html)
        }
    );
    // return any JSON you want
    return response.send({message: 'You HTML was proceed'})
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### Choose View Engine

First of all, you have to choose a view engine, this will be in charge of rendering the template and doing the necessary interpolation.

You can check these view engines:

**Handlebars**: https://handlebarsjs.com/

**Pug**: https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

### Configure the app

Then, you have to create a view and public folders, usually this folder is located in the root layer of your project directory.

[image: View and public folders]

Then, add in your main.ts the following code

[image: Set public and views on app]

This will tell express where are the views (templates) and the public (Css or Js files, etc.) files located.

[image: Set hbs engine]

Add the setViewEngine method indicating the view engine, in this case is handlebars (hbs).

### Create template files

With this configuration you can start creating your templates files, let's see the example on the docs.

[image: handlebars file]

He created a file in the views folder called **index.hbs** and wrote that code, handlebars is basically html and the curly braces indicates that you can put a value on that space.

### Render the file

The last thing to do is on your controller, create a Get method, add the render decorator and put the name of the view file, then return an object containing the values that you want to interpolate on the template and handlebars will do the rest.

[image: Render method]

**If you need more info or have some questions you can leave me a comment :)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I've read tutorial like what you wrote here. 

The tutorial just can't be applied, because, the chatbot will send the message and wouldn't triggering any route. So, that `@Get()` will never triggered.

I also use `telefraf-nestjs`, which using decorator `@On('text')`.

Comment: Could you explain more the use of the view ? What do yo want to be rendered ? And when will you show it ?

Comment: Okay, So, imagine you're chatting with bot (e.g Telegram Bot). For example you send `/start`. Then, the bot will reply `"Hello, {{ telegram user name }}"`. The use of view is to prepare the template for the bot to reply.